# Save a graph in the graph6 format in Python using networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I try to save a graph in `graph6` format in Python with `networkx`. The obvious way does not seem to work:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edge('1','2')
nx.write_graph6(g,"anedge.g6")
g1 = nx.read_graph6("anedge.g6")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nx.draw(g1)
plt.savefig("anedge.pdf")
```

This makes a pdf file showing a graph with two isolated vertices instead of two connected vertices.

Comment: This code sample is not working: `NameError: name 'g' is not defined`.

Comment: I added g = nx.Graph(), now it should work. Sorry for the wrong initial sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `g.add_edge(0, 1)` instead of `g.add_edge('1','2')` it should work:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edge(0, 1)

nx.write_graph6(g, 'anedge.g6')
g1 = nx.read_graph6('anedge.g6')

nx.draw(g1)
plt.savefig("anedge.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually exposing a bug in the networkx graph6 generator when the nodes are not consecutively ordered from zero.  Bug fix is here https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/2739